# How to export Unity particles as static 3D Mesh or 3D Image

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, particle-system, particles

I have some particle system that draws their trails emissive circuits trees :

[image: screenshot of scene]

Actualy, I made a script that "pauses" their simulation, however, I would like to turn them into a mesh or 3D image (maybe an inverted cubemap shader ?).

Anyone knows how I could achieve that?

Comment: "You must log in to continue." Please don't post content relevant to your question behind log-in-only websites. As a matter of fact, don't post **any** relevant content as external links, as they may become inaccessible over time, rendering your question useless to people coming here in the future

Comment: Sorry, don't have enough reputation on Stack overflow to post images or Gifs, i added an alternative link to access the video without any need of logging in.

Comment: If you bring it down to <2mb and upload it on that second platform, I can download it and insert it for you if you like

Comment: Please!!! : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qpelnjjfa0Dr1GebJ0ENrC2WzU16xelB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That file has 7.5mb..

Comment: Made it an Image : https://drive.google.com/file/d/16JCTV70P3tQX0NK-kl5BkM0BcW6Y8Ufg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Here you go, image + upvote

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in or Asset Store support for exporting a "frame" of particles. The Shuriken particle shader is proprietary.

There are alternative particle rendering libraries that may let you do what you want to do.